# how to check that a variable contains something in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Good morning
there are many tutorials that explain how to check if a string is empty but not the other way around

so i would like to do this

if variable not empty then we do this

if not empty then we do this

```
//do the opposite
if (nomvalidation === null || nomvalidation.trim() === ""){

}
```

Comment: If you can check if a string is empty isn’t a non-empty string the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the equality operators to inequality and the or to and and.

```
if (nomvalidation !== null && nomvalidation.trim() !== ""){

}
```

You may also want to look into the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to make sure its a string and [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) as another possible "empty" state.